# Force applications to open on specific screen?

Tags: multiple-monitors, fedora, xorg, xinerama

I'm running Fedora 35 (with X, not Wayland) on a multi-monitor setup. There are two primary monitors, one horizontal and one vertical...

```
                      +---------------+
                      |               |
+--------------------+|               |
|                    ||               |
|                    ||               |
|                    ||               |
|                    ||               |
|                    ||               |
+--------------------+|               |
                      |               |
                      +---------------+
```

...and a Wacom tablet that is also a display (and is turned off unless I am using it). The vertical monitor is used primarily for my browser. I'd like to prevent other applications from opening here, particularly fullscreen things (like video players or games like zsnes).

I'd also like to prevent things from opening up on the Wacom tablet, because it's usually turned off so it's hard to tell the difference between "application failed to open" and "application opened window on the screen that is turned off".

Is there any to influence the behavior of things in a general fashion? Something as simple as "only open on the primary monitor" would be ideal.